# On the spectrum of a quantum mechanical system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, complex-numbers

Can the spectrum of a quantum mechanical operator contain both real and complex numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what part of your question isn't answered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Measurement_probabilities_and_wave_function_collapse

Comment: A spectrum is a property of an operator, not of a system.  Do you mean the spectrum of the Hamiltonian operator?

Comment: @J. Murray, yes i mean a quantum mechanical *operator*. Any operator. Can its spectrum contain both complex and real values ?

Comment: If you want a good answer, you should edit your question to reflect what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectrum of an *operator* can be complex but not the spectrum of an *observable*, pretty much by definition. Consider a two state system with the operator

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This operator has eigenvalues $\pm i$, which obviously are complex. But it is not an observable, because an observable by definition has to be self-adjoint, and $A$ isn't; we demand that an observable be self-adjoint precisely because it guarantees that all eigenvalues will be real.

Edit: I just realized you might be asking whether a single operator can have both real and non-real eigenvalues. In that case,

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

has spectrum $\{1, i, -i\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the boson annihilation operator can be called a "quantum mechanical operator", and it has both real and complex eigenvalues.

Comment: The OP might not know about [coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Quantum_mechanical_definition) yet.

Comment: @CosmasZachos : The OP can always look up "annihilation operator". Furthermore, I often have to repeat that answers are not just for the OP.

Comment: Of course. But readers are lazy... A direct link might bring facts to them...

Comment: @CosmasZachos: Writers can be even lazier:-)